New voting buttons: anyone else find it hard to see if they've voted?
I find the new voting buttons at Chinese.SE hard to see:

At least compared to, say, Meta.SE:

My eyesight is not that bad, but I really have to pay attention to be able to determine whether or not I've voted previously.
Question: Anyone else find it hard to see if they've voted?
(PS. Sorry, my VPN is down at the moment, so I can't see the screenshots myself; I hope they're correct, but if not, please correct them for me.)

Your images are fine. And yes, I find it hard to see, any way we can get the meta SE ones instead?
